# rsync error during incremental backup

Tags: rsync, backup

I am learning how to use `rysnc`  (version 3.0.9,  protocol version 30) to do backup on a toy example, from a dir `/tmp/pdf` to a backup dir `/tmp/backup`, following  http://schlutech.com/2011/11/rsync-full-incremental-differential-snapshots/.

First is a full backup:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/backup
$ ls /tmp/pdf
100  bkg.pdf  p1  stamp.pdf

$ rsync -a /tmp/pdf  /tmp/backup/`date +%Y.%m.%d_%H:%M:%S`/

$ ls /tmp/backup/
2015.02.26_08:36:40   
$ ls /tmp/backup/2015.02.26_08\:36\:40/
pdf
$ ls /tmp/backup/2015.02.26_08\:36\:40/pdf
100  bkg.pdf  p1  stamp.pdf
```

Then I add a new pdf file into the source dir:

```
$ cp /tmp/linux-kernel.pdf /tmp/pdf
$ ls /tmp/pdf
100  bkg.pdf  linux-kernel.pdf  p1  stamp.pdf
```

and do a incremental backup:

```
$ link_dest=`find /tmp/backup -maxdepth 1 -type d | sort | tail -n 1`
$ echo $link_dest
/tmp/backup/2015.02.26_08:36:40

$ rsync -au –link-dest=${link_dest} /tmp/pdf  /tmp/backup/`date +%Y.%m.%d_%H:%M:%S`/
rsync: change_dir "/tmp//–link-dest=/tmp/backup" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1070) [sender=3.0.9]

$ ls /tmp/backup/
2015.02.26_08:36:40  2015.02.26_08:55:47
$ ls /tmp/backup/2015.02.26_08\:55\:47/pdf/
100  bkg.pdf  linux-kernel.pdf  p1  stamp.pdf
```

Why is the `rsync` error above? It seems the second backup has capture the change to the source, i.e. the pdf file I added after the first backup, so I don't see anything wrong?

If it were you, how would you use `rsync` to do incremental backup? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`–link-dest` should be `--link-dest`.

I copied `–link-dest`from the linked webpage, and still don't know how to tell `–` and `-` from each other in a webpage and in terminal. If you know, can you tell me? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the whatever is displaying the page is converting `--` into `&#8211;` (en-dash) as part of it's formatting. The only way to tell is to do what you did followed by `oy vey` or to remember that long-form command line options are generally preceded by `--` and check/take appropriate sction.

Comment: One option to tell characters apart is the [unicode](https://github.com/garabik/unicode) utility.

Comment: This is funny to me that even this lone answer is really a question.  :D